# I accidentally deleted my keys file

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I have been using the wallet perfectly fine for a few months but because my wallet wasn't sending (due to update that I didn't know at the time), I was frantically looking through the wallet folders on my drives and accidentally deleted my wallet keys file for the Monero GUI wallet.

I keep it on an encrypted USB and had to run some recovery software to get the file back but it came back corrupted and does not work.

Are the funds still on the Ledger and how would I retrieve them and get them back into the wallet?

But wait, it gets worst... I then compounded the problem by creating a new wallet from hardware device in the Monero GUI desktop app and sent even more XMR to what I thought was a brand new wallet and address on the same old Ledger.

Well it turns out that it may not have been a brand new address because the coins never came after some time and I thought that was odd, so when I checked the address I sent the XMR to, it was exactly the same address as the old account that I deleted by accident.

I then tried to use the 24 word recovery phrase for my Ledger using the seed recovery option of the Monero wallet (based on some advice), but it said something about my Electrum words failed.

I am just wondering if the Monero still exists on my Ledger Nano S and if it is at all possible to retrieve. Thanks guys.

PS. as you can probably tell I am not at all computer savvy and am lost in listening to some of the brilliant stuff dEBRUYNE and others have been advising. Please help!

Comment: Could you please ask this question on r/monerosupport (Reddit) ?

Comment: You can simply regenerate the `.keys` file with the guide I linked.

Answer (score 1):

The Monero is on the blockchain.

To recover the Monero seed see the section "Seed recovery" in this Ledger guide:

https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006352934-Monero-XMR-

Not easy but remember, the Monero are on the blockchain so there is time to recover the seed. They are only lost if your Monero seed is lost.